# Filter field of manytomany field by a list

Tags: python, django, filter, django-rest-framework

I would like to do the following with Django REST Framework:

Filter results based on a field of a manytomany field.

The query would look like this:
https://endpoint.com/api/artwork/?having_style=Modern,Contemporary

I would expect the result to contain all ArtWork objects which contain a relation to a Style object with name "Modern", "Contemporary" or both.

The code below is not working and I don't know why.

**models.py**

```
class Style(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(validators=[validate_style], max_length=100, unique=True)

class ArtWork(models.Model):
    styles = models.ManyToManyField(Style, default=None)
```

**filters.py**

```
class ArtWorkFilter(filters_rest.FilterSet):
    having_style = django_filters.Filter(field_name="styles__name", lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = ArtWork
        fields = ['having_style']
```

```
class StyleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Style
        fields = ('name',)

class ArtWorkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    styles = StyleSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ArtWork
        fields = ('styles'/)
```

**views.py**

```
class ArtWorkViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = []

    queryset = ArtWork.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArtWorkSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters_rest.DjangoFilterBackend,]
    filterset_class= ArtWorkFilter
    pagination_class = CursorSetPagination
```

Thank you in advance!

### Solution

I solved it by changing the ArtWorkFilter to

**filters.py**

```
class ArtWorkFilter(filters_rest.FilterSet):
    having_style = django_filters.Filter(field_name="styles__name", lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = ArtWork
        fields = ['having_style']

    def filter_by_style_name(self, queryset, name, value):
        list_styles = value.split(',')
        return queryset.filter(styles__name__in=list_styles)
```

Comment: Did you add 'django_filters' to INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes and filtering works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `method` param in Filter declaration. Something like:

```
class ArtWorkFilter(filters_rest.FilterSet):
    having_style = django_filters.Filter(field_name="styles__name", lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = ArtWork
        fields = ['having_style']

    def filter_by_style_name(self, queryset, name, value):
        list_styles = value.split(',')
        return queryset.filter(styles__name__in=list_styles)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart, product=product, attribute__in=attribute_list).annotate(num_attr=Count('attribute')).filter(num_attr=len(attribute_list))
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?